# Receiving "ATT00001.txt" instead of pdf with the mail function

Tags: php, email, pdf

I tried to send a mail with an attachement with the mail function, I found a tutorial for a JPG and tried to modify it for sending PDF, but the only attachement I receive is `ATT00001.txt`.

Here is my programm:

```
<?php
// To
$to = 'mail@test.com';

// Subject
$subject = 'Test pdf';

// random boundary
$boundary = md5(uniqid(microtime(), TRUE));

// Headers
$headers = 'From: Test <mail@test.com>'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Mime-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary='.$boundary."\r\n";
$headers .= "\r\n";

// Message
$msg = 'This is a multipart/mixed message.'."\r\n\r\n";

// Text
$msg .= '--'.$boundary."\r\n";
$msg .= 'Content-type:text/plain;charset=utf-8'."\r\n";
$msg .= 'Content-transfer-encoding:8bit'."\r\n";
$msg .= 'Un message avec une pièce jointe.'."\r\n";

// Attachement
$file_name = 'test.pdf';
if (file_exists($file_name))
{
    $file_type = filetype($file_name);
    $file_size = filesize($file_name);

    $handle = fopen($file_name, 'r') or die('File '.$file_name.'can t be open');
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $f = fclose($handle);

    $msg .= '--'.$boundary."\r\n";
    $msg .= 'Content-type:'.$file_type.';name='.$file_name."\r\n";
    $msg .= 'Content-transfer-encoding:base64'."\r\n";
    $msg .= $content."\r\n";
}

// End
$msg .= '--'.$boundary."\r\n";

// Function mail()
mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
echo "test pdf";
?>
```

I hope you could help me,

Best regards ☻♥

Comment: Unsure but this may help - http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4981187

Comment: Oh, also - I would strongly recommend you use something like Swiftmailer -
 https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer instead. This will abstract all the nitty gritty low level mail stuff for you and ensure its all formatted correctly.